# adb logcat returns "Logcat read failure"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

After noticing that Logcat messages were not showing up in Android Studio, I tried every solution out there, and nothing worked. I eventually tried the command `adb devices` and sure enough my device was there, but as soon as I tried `adb logcat` it returned "logcat read failure".

Developer settings are turned on, and so it debugging. I'm on a rooted phone running 7.0 Nougat, with an open bootloader.

Could it be that I'm rooted and it somehow messed up some permissions? I've never encountered this issue before, even on a rooted phone.

Logcat works when using an emulator.

Comment: Have you tried plugging it out and in again? Serious question. Is the cable working properly with other devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue as yours. Then I asked the developer of the ROM if he is facing the same issue. The developer said that it is working fine for him. So I flashed the ROM again and noticed that logcat was properly working. So it was clear that the problem was due to some apps or changes that I did on the ROM.

**After debugging , I found that it was ARISE Sound System that was the root cause of this problem for me.**

So if your are using ARISE Sound System dirty flash the ROM to remove it and check if this solves the problem for you. For now I am only using Viper4Android.

Comment: Oh man, I was so pumped to read your reply as I did have ARISE installed, but unfortunately it did not solve my problem.. I dirty flashed, and now I do not have ARISE, and I'm still receiving the "logcat read failure"..

Comment: I did another dirty flash to remove the root, and I only used it for ARISE, and it works now!! So the root was the cause of the problem!

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem and I did the same than you removed ARISE, but now I don't have notifications sounds :(

Comment: So, what if they don't using ARISE Sound system? Does it mean that answer is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use alogcat ROOT app.  Is it work on the device? [App link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rs.pedjaapps.alogcatroot.app)

Comment: Installed it, gave it root access, and still nothing shows up. Blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

So, post here right answer because I spent a such many time to solve this.
Ok, when in Android Studio I start debug an app on real Smart TV device I saw in logcat nothing. When I ran "logcat" on device directly I got "logcat read failure"
A year before I removed "logd" from "system/bin" and this was a problem.. but I forgot about it. Even if I've copied it back it doesn't work. Because **SELinuxe Security Context**

Solution: give the **logd** it's context back with a **chcon** util.
More details you can find here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-restore-logd-to-your-device-fix-adb-logcat-read-failure-or-empty-logs.3512946/#post-69930494